# Regex, help me on get only first occurrance inside a string avoiding search after certain char Vb.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am try to make working a regex inside a VB.NET program.
I've got a text file with many lines that define coordinates and other variables where lines look like this:

N1111G83X4.0Y-2.5Z3.45 [this is comment on X4.0

Basically what I want to do is with the help of regex match every variables like X-Y-Z , extract the numerical positive or negative value of the first occurrence of them and if there is one or many occurrence with a [ character before of them not consider the match at all. On the text line could happen that the coordinate could have one white space between each others but usually not
I did just a plain test with the small regex 
`([X][-]?\d+[,.]?\d+)` but of course I got 2 results where I'd like to ignore the X4.0 one. If anyone could help I will be really happy coz I'm bumping my head all the day on it today. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try [`Regex.Matches(s, "(?<!\[.*)(?<var>[XYZ])(?<val>-?\d*[,.]?\d+)")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5b.*%29%28%3f%3cvar%3e%5bXYZ%5d%29%28%3f%3cval%3e-%3f%5cd*%5b%2c.%5d%3f%5cd%2b%29&i=N1111G83X4.0Y-2.5Z3.45+%5bthis+is+comment+on+X4.0)

Comment: Please provide more sample input, some which should match, some which should not match and especially some tricky, which look at first glance like they should match but actually should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick consists of using a negative look-behind. The expression `(?<!pattern)find` means that we only want matches of `find` that do not occur after `pattern`. We define `pattern` as `\[.*`, i.e. a `[` followed any number of any characters. That's the comment that you want to exclude.

```
Dim input As String = "N1111G83X4.0Y-2.5Z3.45 [this is comment on X4.0"
Dim regex = New Regex("(?<!\[.*)[XYZ](\+|-)?\d+[,.]?\d+")
Dim matches = regex.Matches(input)
For Each match As Match In matches
    'E.g. match.Value = "Y-2.5"
    Dim coord = Left(match.Value, 1) 'E.g. "Y"
    Dim val = Mid(match.Value, 2)    'E.g. "-2.5"
    Dim num = Double.Parse(val.Replace(","c, "."c))
    Console.WriteLine($"{coord} = {num}")
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

This prints

> X = 4
>   Y = -2.5
>   Z = 3.45

The rest of the pattern is

```
[XYZ](\+|-)?\d+[,.]?\d+
```

I.e.

```
[XYZ]          The coordinate name
(\+|-)?        "+" or "-" or nothing
\d+[,.]?\d+    A number
```

I also took care of replacing "," characters by "." before parsing.

---

A slightly different pattern allows you to capture different parts of the match into named groups. The syntax is `(?<name>find)`. This saves you some string manipulations

```
Dim input As String = "N1111G83X4.0Y-2.5Z3.45 [this is comment on X4.0"
Dim regex = New Regex("(?<!\[.*)(?<coord>[XYZ])(?<val>(\+|-)?\d+[,.]?\d+)")
Dim matches = regex.Matches(input)
For Each match As Match In matches
    Dim coord = match.Groups("coord").Value
    Dim val = match.Groups("val").Value
    Dim num = Double.Parse(val.Replace(","c, "."c))
    Console.WriteLine($"{coord} = {num}")
Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: First of all all thank you so much @Olivier for your help on my problem, I decide to follow your suggestion regarding the formula:
Dim regex = New Regex("(?<!\[.*)(?<coord>[XYZJIQKF])(?<val>(\+|-)?\d+[,.]?\d+)")
But as on the example up there I have to add another question.
It could happen that instead of [ as a comment delimitator I have a //
as well as that by error (it shall not be possible but I like to prevent error ....) I need the presence of only the first occurrance of X or Y or Z inside the string. 
N1111G83X4.0Y-2.5Z3.45X8.00 [this is comment on X4.0
I shall get an error

Comment: Another question regard the double conversion of the coordinates, sadly if I get the 8.5 converted in double it become 85 because with current culture double is not dot separated, But that's another problem I guess. 
You really help me a lot in this one. Where could I find more on the Regex in the .Net ambient ? I never seen before the named group options. Best regards

Comment: The adding // is strightforward: `(?<!(\[|//).*)(?<coord>(?<var>[XYZ])(?<val>(\+|-)?\d+[,.]?\d+))` (just replace `(?<!\[.*)` by `(?<!(\[|//).*)`. As for the parsing, use `Double.Parse(val.Replace(","c, "."c), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: thank you Olivier I did it before you reply, I learn a little bit from regex thanks to you and best regards –